# Sequential dependent functions in Vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, contentful

I'm currently building a Vue app that consumes data from the Contentful API. For each entry, I have a `thumbnail` (image) field from which I'd like to extract the prominent colours as hex values and store them in the state to be used elsewhere in the app.

Using a Vuex action (getAllProjects) to query the API, run Vibrant ([node-vibrant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vibrant)) and commit the response to the state.

```
async getAllProjects({ commit }) {
    let {
      fields: { order: order }
    } = await api.getEntry("entry");
    let projects = order;

    projects.forEach(p =>
      Vibrant.from(`https:${p.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.url}`)
        .getPalette()
        .then(palette => (p.fields.accent = palette.Vibrant.hex))
    );

    console.log(projects);

    // Commit to state
    commit("setAllProjects", projects);
  }
```

When I log the contents of `projects` right before I call `commmit`, I can see the hex values I'm after *are* added under the `accent` key. However, when I inspect the mutation payload in devtools, the `accent` key is missing, and so doesn't end up in the state.

How do I structure these tasks so that `commit` only fires *after* the API call and Vibrant have run in sequence?

Comment: Are you certain that accent is found at all in projects?  The forEach() method does not mutate the array it is operating on to begin with.

Comment: @crosen9999 The `accent` key isn't present in the API response, I'm trying to add that key and assign its value to be the output of `Vibrant.getPalette()`, and then commit the modified array (including the original response values plus the new `accent` key) to the state.

*Edit:* the `accent` field is not part of the content model, so when I say the key is not part of the API response, that behaviour is expected.

Comment: What I mean is that the code would not appear to add the property to projects because forEach does not modify projects; it modifies a copy of each element.  Please try my answer below and see if that works.

Comment: I don't know Vibrant very well, to me it seems like a timing issue with the looped callbacks, and from what I can read you can choose to go with promises. In that case there are many options, but to test that out, you could just commit inside every .then() call, and overwrite with new data till the end (this is horrible) but if it works, we can find a good solution that waits for the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a property to an object in Vue and have it be reactive; you must use the Vue.set method.

Please try replacing that forEach block with the following, which adds the new property using Vue.set:

```
    for (i=0; i<projects.length; i++)
      Vibrant.from(`https:${projects[i].fields.thumbnail.fields.file.url}`)
        .getPalette()
        .then(palette => (Vue.set(projects[i].fields, accent, palette.Vibrant.hex)))
    );
```

UPDATE: changing the format from forEach to a conventional for loop may be gratuitous in this case, since the assignment being made is to an object property of projects and not to a primitive.

Comment: X.forEach((e, i) => { ... }); Serves the same purpose, only forEach must arguably be more readable than the good old for loop.

Comment: "forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called.".  Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Neither does for(), you are using the index to mutate the values of the initial order, you could achieve the same with forEach() by using the index param. 

You could do the same by using map(), which actually returns an array (DONT DO THIS) but you can.

Comment: const foo = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
foo.forEach((e, i) => {
  foo[i]++;
});

console.log(foo); Works fine, this is NOT his issue.

Comment: But he is NOT using an index as you did; he is using the p argument from forEach, which will not change projects.  He can choose to use an index while keeping the forEach, but currently he is not doing so.

Comment: I'm very capable of being wrong, let me just point that out. But projects is an array, p is a "pointer" to an instance of an object in that array. It's referenced by memory, and as such changing a key on it, will globally change the value for anything that might use it. My codepen does again work in this case, even without index.

Comment: Please see the sample code I added to the end of my answer to illustrate how forEach is not changing projects and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @crosen9999 After swapping out .forEach for a regular loop and assigning the new data using `Vue.set`, the new `accent` value gets successfully loaded into the state - there's a slight delay while `Vibrant.getPalette()` calculates the values from the fetched image URLs but I'm happy with this solution as I'm going to implement some sort of  loading state further down the line. Thanks for your suggestions + particularly for introducing me to `Vue.set`!

Comment: Your completely right in your test, but I'm using objects (non-primitive) - (NaN, function, object etc.) you are using ints (primitives) - (Boolean, int, string), and these are not stored in memory the same. So we are comparing apples and oranges here :)

const projects = [{foo: 1},{foo: 2}];
projects.forEach(p => {
  p.foo++;
});

Comment: Actually, in that case, you are correct in the bottom line, since he is using objects.  So, the issue was Vue.set, and not forEach.  Thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not spending a lot of time on StackOverflow, and if the above answer works, I am happy for you indeed.

But I expect from that answer you will get console warnings telling you not to mutate state directly.

Now when this happens, it's because while Vue.set(), does in fact help Vue understand reactively a change has been made, potentially deeply nested in an object.

The problem here is that since you are looping the object, changing it all the time, the commit (Mutator call) is not the one changing state - Vue.set() is actually changing it for every iteration.